# list index out of range, algoritmo genético

Tags: python

Estou com problemas na linha que está `parcial += pacum [i-1]` estou com o erro "list index out of range", sobre as váriaveis e listas: lista populacao e fitness dependem do tamanhoPopulacao que pode ser qualquer valor inteiro.

```
def selecao(fitness, populacao):
    populacaoIntermediaria=[]
    somatotal = sum(fitness)
    probSelecao = []
    pacum = []

    for j in range(len(fitness)):
        probSelecao.append(fitness[j]/somatotal)
        pacum.append(sum(probSelecao))
        print('Pacum({}): {}'.format(j, pacum[j]))

    for j in range(tamPopulacao):

        i = 1
        parcial = 0
        r = uniform(0, somatotal)

        while (r >= parcial or i == len(pacum)):
            print('Posição{}'.format(i))
            parcial += pacum[i-1]
            i += 1

            print('Parcial: {}'.format(parcial))
        populacaoIntermediaria.append(populacao[i-1])

    print('População Intermediaria: {}'.format(populacaoIntermediaria))

    return  populacaoIntermediaria
```

Comment: Seu while está sendo executado mais vezes do que a quantidade de elementos em pacnum.

Comment: Sim exato, porém como resolver? pois não estou entendendo porque ele está ficando maior, até decrementei uma posição da função len.

Answer (score 1):

Bom para quem queira usar a resolução do problema, eu resolvi era um problema de lógica. Código corrigido:

```
def selecao(fitness, populacao):
    populacaoIntermediaria=[]
    somatotal = sum(fitness)
    probSelecao = []
    pacum = []

    for j in range(0, len(fitness)):
        probSelecao.append(fitness[j]/somatotal)
        pacum.append(sum(probSelecao))

        print('Pacum({}): {}'.format(j, pacum[j]))

    for j in range(tamPopulacao):

        i = 0
        parcial = 0
        r = uniform(0, somatotal)

        while (i != len(pacum)):
            print('Parcial ({}): {}'.format(i, parcial))
            parcial += pacum[i]
            i += 1
            if (parcial >= r):
                 break
        populacaoIntermediaria.append(populacao[i-1])

    print('População Intermediaria: {}'.format(populacaoIntermediaria))

    return  populacaoIntermediaria
```